# SQL Date Calculation formatting

Tags: sql, oracle, date

It's been a while since I posted. I have an issue regarding date calculations.

I am trying to find the difference between two dates as in start time and finish time.

I have been able to find the difference in days so for instance if I have the dates:

```
start = 12/11/2014 12:05:05
finish = 13/11/2014 09:44:19
```

then the query gives me -0.90224537......

However, I need the answer in the form of hours, minutes, seconds for wage purposes. What is the best way of doing this?

My query so far is:

```
select
    time_sheet.time_sheet_id, 
    time_sheet.start_date_time - time_sheet.finish_date_time,     
    employee_case.case, employee_case.employee 
from 
    time_sheet 
inner join 
    employee_case on time_sheet.employee_case = employee_case.employee_case_id 
where 
    employee_case.case = 1;
```

P.S. I am using an Oracle database :)

Comment: Thanks for editing it to read correctly @marc_s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`date - date` yields the difference in `days`. So you can use the standard time conversion to convert it to hours,minutes and seconds as below:

```
select
    time_sheet.time_sheet_id, 
    (time_sheet.finish_date_time - time_sheet.start_date_time)||' days'||(time_sheet.finish_date_time - time_sheet.start_date_time)*24||' hours '||(time_sheet.finish_date_time - time_sheet.start_date_time)*24*60||' minutes '||(time_sheet.finish_date_time - time_sheet.start_date_time)*24*60*60||' seconds ' ,     
    employee_case.case, employee_case.employee 
from 
    time_sheet 
inner join 
    employee_case on time_sheet.employee_case = employee_case.employee_case_id 
where 
    employee_case.case = 1;
```

Also, you would need `finish_date_time` as the minuend and `start_date_time` as the subtrahend to avoid negative values.

Comment: That doesnt quite work the way I want. I probably wasnt clear in my question. I want it so that given the dates provided in question, the answer would be 21h 39m 14s whereas what you have given is for it to give me the duration in different units not split between hours minutes and seconds. sorry for any confusion

Comment: Darago, I understand. I'm sure there exist some function somewhere (maybe not Oracle default) that shows a nice readable format, translated from "0,9" to "21h 39m 14s" (or whatever is the actual value). It's not that easy, since you problably don't want to see this "0days 0h 39m 14s" ? Which is more easy than "39m 14s" (assuming less than 1 hour).

Comment: @tvCa You are absolutely right. There is one: `select numtodsinterval(2.7,'Day') from dual;`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help toddlermenot but i have decided to go another way I have found. For anybody else who has the same issue I have done the following:

```
select
    time_sheet.time_sheet_id, 
    to_number( to_char(to_date('1','J') +
    (time_sheet.finish_date_time - time_sheet.start_date_time), 'J') - 1)  days,
    to_char(to_date('00:00:00','HH24:MI:SS') +
    (time_sheet.finish_date_time - time_sheet.start_date_time), 'HH24:MI:SS') time,
    employee_case.case, employee_case.employee 
from 
    time_sheet 
inner join 
    employee_case on time_sheet.employee_case = employee_case.employee_case_id 
where 
    employee_case.case = 1;
```

This seems to do exactly what I need. It does the days in a serperate field to the hours minutes and seconds but for my purposes this is acceptable